# Javascript/ Bootstrap/ JQuery doesn't load when switching domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a website on one domain, perfecting it to my likings. However, now I took all the files, copied them to another domain. Now the website console throws weird errors, that were not there on the first domain where the website was created.

I get errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on
>   bootstrap.min.js`and Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument
>   list on jquerymagnific-popup.js`

In the code, I am referring to all scripts with the following line(s):

```
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

I can't seem to figure out why it works on for example `domain1.com/testing` but not on `domain2.com`

Comment: use console to check .if all files loded correctly..

Comment: are you using plesk?

Comment: The console only shows the Uncaught SyntaxErrors.

Comment: It's just a webhost, so not sure wheter Plesk is installed.

Comment: Upload again those files by FTP, first as binary, I had a lot of issues like this with PHP and JS files uploaded as ASCII, I guess it's something about the new line character.

Comment: That did not fix the issue unfortunately, thanks anyway Triby!